# Script unexpectedly exits if a directory doesn't exist

Tags: linux, bash, find

I am writing a shell script and try to search for all files in some locations. The locations have a variable. Like this:

```
CONFDIRS = (~/.config/syncer /etc/syncer ~/etc/syncer)
```

So, I have written a for loop to display all possible files:

```
search() {  #search for possible configurations
for i in ${CONFDIRS[@]}; do
        find $i -type f 
done

return 1
}
```

My problem is, if one directory not exists, the program quit with an error. If I use `2>/dev/null`, the program quit without an error, but the program shouldn't quit. How can I do that?

Comment: Why not just `find "${CONFDIRS[@]}" -type f 2>/dev/null`? What do you need loop for?

Comment: Guys, it sounds more like OP set (knowingly or unknowingly) -e flag

Comment: As what OP has mentioned in the question, it should ideally work, only thing should be quoting the variables! and i'm not sure why there's space in defining the `CONFDIRS`!!!

Comment: @Max : Why do you keep it as a secret, what kind of error you got?

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `CONFDIRS` is unset if you "defined" it using

```
CONFDIRS = (...)
```

Note the spaces around `=`. Simply remove them.

It also doesn't hurt to quote your variables. Write `"$i"` instead of `$i`.

Comment: If that was the issue, OP would get a command not found error though

Comment: I think that actually might be the case. OP's description `the program quit with an error` is not really precise. Maybe `the program` is the whole script and OP has `set -e` enabled.